# jQuery Highlight Effect with no fade away

Tags: jquery

I want to highlight a `<span>` using jQuery.effect('highlight'), but it fades out after a period of time.

How can I get the highlight to be persistent?

My code is:

```
 $('span').live('click', function () {
        $(this).effect("highlight", { color: "#ff3fff"});
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the highlight effect has a persistant state, you could just set the background colour:

```
$('span').live('click', function () {
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", "#ff3fff");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `UI`, try this:

```
$('span').live('click', function () {
   $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#aa0000', color: '#fff'}, 1000);
});
```

Since jQuery UI has the `color plugin` integrated, you can animate color fading aswell.