# Highlight multiple search results in jqGrid tree

Tags: search, jqgrid, tree, multi-select

I have a tree Grid where I want to provide for a Search facility and highlight the results in a tree. I looked at the link [How to search for a row and then select it in jqGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791020/how-to-search-for-a-row-and-then-select-it-in-jqgrid/3798151#3798151) and the same works fine.

However my Grid is a tree and as mentioned in the link [Selecting multiple rows in jqGrid tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257996/selecting-multiple-rows-in-jqgrid-tree), MultiSelect:true option does not work. Hence when I search for a pattern, only the last row with the matching pattern is highlighted. I want to know how to highlight all the rows with the matching pattern.

The solution provided in the link [Access jqgrid elements using a javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817489/access-jqgrid-elements-using-a-javascript/5819136#5819136) suggests providing checkboxes to get a list of selected rows, but my requirement is to highlight the rows which satisfy the search result.

If this description is not sufficient, I will provide for my jqgrid definition, but I thought this is a generic issue and hence am currently not pasting the same.

Thanks much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I changed the background color of the rows that match the search pattern and that served my purpose. Another link that helped me is - [jQuery Highlight Effect with no fade away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116616/jquery-highlight-effect-with-no-fade-away?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the id's of the rows that have matches..

You can do..

```
//matchingRowIds

$.each(matchingRowIds, function(rowId, _){
    grid.setSelection(rowId); //or however it is that you're selecting the row
});
```

Note: Do not call `resetSelection()` whilst calling `setSelection()`